# Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB is missing from SSIS

Tags: ssis

I can't find **Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB** in the drop menu in an integration service services project "**SSIS**"
[image: list of available providers.png]

However, I can find this provider in SQL Server, and its working fine
[image: Sql Server.png]

Please any idea hotfix this problem, it should look like this
[image: what I'm looking for.png]

What I tried so far :
-I installed: AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 2016

-I installed: data storage and processing workload using vs_community installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studios (SSDT) is a 32-bit application.   It will only display 32 bit drivers in the options to select from.